# innerHTML in Javascript causing error in multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 HTML pages which I linked to 1 javascript file.

In the javascript file, I use innerHTML to get a value from HTML file 1, but the issue is that an error pops up in HTML page 2 as it cannot find the same value. Is there a way for me to only check HTML page 1 for the value instead of both pages?

**HTML page 1**

```
    <div id = "html1"> Value </div>
    <script src = script.js></script>
```

**HTML page 2**

```
    <div id = "html2"> Another Value </div>
    <script src = script.js></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
x = document.getElementById("html1").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add conditions for performing actions. something like

```js
if (document.getElementById('html1')) // will return null if doesn't exist.
  x = document.getElementById("html1").innerHTML;
```

But consider separating script files if pages aren't related.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```js
// Shortcut
const s = t => document.getElementById(t);

// Inline false check:
// variable = (if condition true) ? then this value : or this value if condition false
const x = s("html1") ? s("html1").innerHTML : false;
const y = s("html2") ? s("html2").innerHTML : false;

console.log(x, y);
```

```html
<div id = "html1">Value</div>
```